# Screen resolution on xfce4 on VPS using xrdp

Tags: debian, xfce, vps, xrdp

Thought id have a go at having a VPS running Debian Buster and installing a GUI and connecting to it using RDP (Reminna).

I installed as below

```
sudo apt-get -y install xfce4 xfonts-base tightvncserver xrdp
```

I can RDP in no problem remotely, and log in, but the screen solution in xfce (v4.12) display settings is fixed at 642x480 and there seems no way to amend this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwFPI.png

Any ideas?

I am using Reminna as RDP client but the auto scale resolution is not working.

Comment: What does `xrandr` show? Does `cvt 1920 1080` show anything?

Comment: I reconnected using Reminna but this time in Reminna's settings I actually added the server as a config and specified a resolution of 1024x768 and when I connected, it was in that res.

When in the GUI, xrand reports that res (cannot seem to copy/paste the output at all)

Comment: cvt 1920 1080 outputs two lines of code, which I cannot copy/paste for some reason, but the first line (typed here manually) says #1920x1080 59.96Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz;173.000 MHz

Comment: **cvt** gives the information that xrandr needs to add new resolutions. With this, you should be able to set your resolution to whatever your screen can handle.

Comment: I've amended reminna setting to 'use client resolution' and it just works perfectly now. Ta